# Using Rally API how to find all the projects for which the user has write access?

Tags: java, api, rally

I have write access for few projects in Rally. But I need find out the entire list using the Rally API. Is there any way to do this?

I tried to find out UserPermissions as mentioned [here](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/ObjectID/UserPermissions) using the link - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/user/ObjectID/UserPermissions

But that did not show any useful data.

P.S. I am not a Rally Admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the Project Permissions for your user, you can use the ProjectPermission endpoint:

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission?fetch=Role,Workspace,Project

Comment: Thanks, I modified it a little so that role as "Viewer" is filtered out - `https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/projectpermission?fetch=Role,Workspace,Project&query=(Role != "Viewer")`